# Как сделать добавление пользователей в группу ботом ? (telebot)

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, бот

Надо что бы бот при определенной команде мог добавлять человека в закрытую группу. Можно ли сделать это с библиотекой Telebot ? (python)

Answer (score 0):

если у вас есть id того, кого хотите добавить, то да, просто тупо заносить в БД запись в соответствующую табл и все